# 'is an element of $\emptyset$' vs 'were an element of $\emptyset$'

Tags: logic

> [[Source:]](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ewtg10/implication.html) ... think a bit more about the seemingly obvious fact that, if A is a set, then $\emptyset$ is one of its subsets. To prove that, we need
> to establish the following:
>
> [$1.$] every element of $\emptyset$ is an element of A. (+)
>
> What is our instinctive reaction to that? Mine is to say, "Yes, that's
> true because there **aren't** any elements of  $\emptyset$, $\color{red} { [4.]}  \;$ so those
> that there **are** " (and here I might give a little apologetic laugh)
> "are elements of A."
>
> Now let us look at a different formulation of
> what we need.
>
> [$2.$] If x is an element of $\emptyset$, then x is an element of A.
>
> I think it is possible to feel this sentence as
> reasonable or unreasonable. It seems reasonable if you say to yourself
> that it means exactly the same as [1] and $\color{red} { [5.]}  \;$  unreasonable if you think of
> it in a more counterfactual way, as saying something like
>
> [$3.$] if x were
> an element of $\emptyset$ then it would be an element of A.
>
> $\color{red} { [6.]}  \;$ This
> last sentence is another one that forces us to try to imagine an
> impossible situation
> (this time forgetting that  $\emptyset$ has to
> be, well, empty).

$\color{red} { 4.   }$ Why would instinct motivate you to imagine elements of $\emptyset$?
What does the author (Gowers) mean? We know that $\emptyset$ contains no elements.

$\color{red} { 5.   }$ Why does [2.] seem unreasonable if you think of it counterfactually?
The protasis for [2.] also is impossible; so  $\color{red} { [6.]}  \;$ also applies to $2$?

Comment: Mine is to say: "Yes, that's true because there are no elements of $\varnothing$ with the property of not being an element of $A$. Even stronger: there are no elements of $\varnothing$ at all."

Comment: Yes. "If x were an element of $\varnothing$ then it would be an element of A" is a TRUE statement. Since "x is an element of $\varnothing$" is FALSE, then "If x were an element of $\varnothing$ then it would be an element of A" tells you nothing about the truth or falsity of "x is an element of A$.

Comment: You have seen the truth table of $\implies$ ("implies") right? The following are all true statements: $T\implies T$ (even if the two truths don't seem related), $F\implies T$, and $F\implies F$ (these last two usually seem odd at first). The statement "$T\implies F$" is false.

Comment: Since you already know that $\emptyset\subseteq A$, and you are asking rather about how Gowers' instincts work and whether/why the meanings of his statements differ, this seems to be more a question of linguistics and/or psychology than a question of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

$x \in \emptyset \to x \in A$ is vacuously true because the hypothesis is false.

We are motivated to imagine the elements of $\emptyset$, so we can do vacuous proofs like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are having trouble with the meaning of $\rightarrow$.

In particular, $F\rightarrow F$ AND $F\rightarrow T$ are both TRUE statements.

This is sort of what teachers mean when they say that if you start with a FALSE proposition, then you can prove anything. This is why. When someone "proves" that $1 = 0$, you know that, somewhere in his proof, there is hidden a FALSE proposition.

You use words like "counterfactual" and "impossible situation". I think you are assuming that, because $FALSE \rightarrow S$ is TRUE, then S must be TRUE. No. It's not the same thing.